# how to calculate and use cvMat mean value

Tags: c++, opencv, matrix, mean

In the openCV cheat sheet (C++), I have found the matrix opration [`mean()`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga191389f8a0e58180bb13a727782cd461). When I use it:

```
float myMatMean = mean( MyMat );
```

I get the error:

> no suitable conversion function from "cv::Scalar" to "float" exists

What can I do in order to use this data?

Comment: `mean()` appears to be returning a variable of type `cv::Scalar` so try `cv::Scalar myMatMean = mean(MyMat);`

Comment: I think it works using double instead of float, if you dont want to bother with Scalar. But Scalar gives you mean across all channels

Answer (score 44):

Thanks.

The problem was that although `myMat` was a 2D image. The return type was still a `Scalar` of size **4**.

The solution was

```
cv::Scalar tempVal = cv::mean( myMat );
float myMAtMean = tempVal.val[0];
```

Comment: what is mean? which header? which namesmace? please put the used namespaces when you use such non standard functions.

Comment: The problem is not that "the image is 2D" but that an image can have multiple color planes (B,G,R normally for color images in openCV) and the mean value is taken per color plane giving you one value per color plane hence the Scalar. Your solution gives you the average of the blue portion of the image (unless that is a grayscale image).