# OpenCV - Mean of Mat object in C++

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

How can we get the mean of an input RGB image(3 dimensional Mat object) so that we get a gray image? The `cvtColor()` function of OpenCV converts the image to gray based on a pre-existing formula. I want to get the mean of all three channels and store the resultant image in another matrix. The `cv::mean()` function in OpenCV returns the scalar mean of all input channels.

Were this Python, with `img` being a RGB image, `img.mean(2)` would get me what I want. Successive calls of the `addWeighted()` function and using `gray= blue/3.0 + red/3.0 +green/3.0` [ After splitting channels] yielded different results when compared with Python.

Is there anything analogous to `img.mean(2)` in C++ or the OpenCV library of C++?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Apply function to each pixel of the image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22329318/apply-function-to-each-pixel-of-the-image)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is there anything analogous to img.mean(2) in C++ or the OpenCV library of C++?

No, but you can easily compute that. There are a few ways of doing it:

1. Loop over all the image, and set each value as the mean of the input pixel values. Take care of computing the intermediate values for the mean on a type with more capacity and accuracy than `uchar` (here I used `double`) or you may end up with wrong results. You can also optimize the code further, e.g. see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34308932/5008845) and its answers. You just need to change the function computed in the inner loop to compute the mean.
2. Use `reduce`. You can `reshape` you 3 channel matrix of size `rows x cols` to be a matrix of shape ((rows*cols) x 3), and then you can use the `reduce` operation with parameter `REDUCE_AVG` to compute the average row-wise. Then `reshape` the matrix to correct size. `reshape` operation is very fast, since you just modify the header without affecting the stored data.
3. Use matrix operations to sum channels. You can use `split` to get the matrix for each channel, and sum them. Take care to not saturate your values while summing up! *(Thanks to [beaker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42018164/opencv-mean-of-mat-object-in-c/42022152?noredirect=1#comment71257510_42022152) for this one.)*

You can see that the first approach is faster with small matrices, but as soon as the size increase, the second approach performs much better since you take advantage of OpenCV optimizations.
The third approach works surprisingly well (thanks to matrix expressions).

Some numbers, time in ms. Time may vary on you computer depending on OpenCV optimizations enabled. Run in release!

```
Size  : 10x10   100x100   1000x1000   10000x10000
Loop  : 0.0077  0.3625    34.82       3456.71
Reduce: 1.44    1.42      8.88        716.75
Split : 0.1158  0.0656    2.26304     246.476
```

Code:

```
#include <opencv2\opencv.hpp>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main()
{
    Mat3b img(1000, 1000);
    randu(img, Scalar(0, 0, 0), Scalar(10, 10, 10));


    {
        double tic = double(getTickCount());
        Mat1b mean_img(img.rows, img.cols, uchar(0));
        for (int r = 0; r < img.rows; ++r) {
            for (int c = 0; c < img.cols; ++c) {
                const Vec3b& v = img(r, c);
                mean_img(r, c) = static_cast<uchar>(round((double(v[0]) + double(v[1]) + double(v[2])) / 3.0));
            }
        }
        double toc = (double(getTickCount()) - tic) * 1000.0 / getTickFrequency();
        cout << "Loop: " << toc << endl;
    }

    {
        double tic = double(getTickCount());

        Mat1b mean_img2 = img.reshape(1, img.rows*img.cols);
        reduce(mean_img2, mean_img2, 1, REDUCE_AVG);
        mean_img2 = mean_img2.reshape(1, img.rows);

        double toc = (double(getTickCount()) - tic) * 1000.0 / getTickFrequency();
        cout << "Reduce: " << toc << endl;
    }

    {
        double tic = double(getTickCount());

        vector<Mat1b> planes;
        split(img, planes);
        Mat1b mean_img3;
        if (img.channels() == 3) {
            mean_img3 = (planes[0] + planes[1] + planes[2]) / 3.0;
        }

        double toc = (double(getTickCount()) - tic) * 1000.0 / getTickFrequency();
        cout << "Split: " << toc << endl;
    }


    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Interesting comparison. Did you try splitting the channels, adding them and dividing by 3? You'd have to be careful that the Mat type was big enough to hold the sum, though.

Comment: @beaker no, but it should be much slower, since you need to allocate "number of channel" matrices. I'll try that later. Thanks for the tip

Comment: @beaker I had done that, but the results were not the same.

Comment: @beaker that works surprisingly well. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: @Ashwin check updated answer. In fact beaker suggestions work very well

Comment: My bad. I had tried that before, but my matrix was most likely not big enough to hold all values. I guess, one should add those values in a matrix that is big enough, divide the matrix by 3; and then assign these values to a uchar matrix or cast the end result as a uchar matrix.

Comment: @Ashwin yep, that's why Matrix Expressions are useful ;)

Comment: Cool beans! Thanks for testing it out Miki :)

Answer (score 0):

## **mean()**

Calculates an average (mean) of array elements.

**C++:** Scalar mean(InputArray src, InputArray mask=noArray())

**Python:** cv2.mean(src[, mask]) → retval

**C:** CvScalar cvAvg(const CvArr* arr, const CvArr* mask=NULL )

**Python:** cv.Avg(arr, mask=None) → scalar

**Parameters:** 
src – input array that should have from 1 to 4 channels so that the result can be stored in Scalar_ .
mask – optional operation mask.

The function mean calculates the mean value M of array elements, independently for each channel, and return it:

When all the mask elements are 0’s, the functions return Scalar::all(0) .

*Also check this answer [how to calculate and use cvMat mean value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12687437/how-to-calculate-and-use-cvmat-mean-value)*